gin router 404 on url patterns with :id parameter
I am getting a 404 error from a URL pattern with a quite simple parameter in it.
I am using gin-gonic with golang.
Here is my main programme. I've removed all other routing to isolate the problem.
func main() {
    r := gin.Default()

    r.GET("/action/:id", controllers.ActionHandler)
    r.GET("/home", controllers.Home)

    config.Init()

    r.LoadHTMLGlob("./templates/*/*")

    // routes.AuthRoutes(r)
    
    r.Run("localhost:8080")
}

When the programme runs, the browser recognises "/home".
But it does not recognise "/action/demand"
I'm flummoxed

This seems to be a Firefox cache problem. It is hard to reproduce reliably because it occurs some of the time but not all of the time.
The symptom is that the browser redirects to "/"' and reports a 404 'page not found' in response to the URL "/action/demand"`.
This goes away if I clear the firefox cache. But then recurs.
The problem only seems to occur on firefox
I haven't found a fix yet except to use another browser.
